# Block/content segment (category: template) in new-relic server perf monitoring graph

Tags: newrelic

It's not documented in NR University thus I'm asking it here. What's the `Block/content` segment in NR's application monitoring graphs?

I ask about this so I can explore reducing the response time. A screenshot follows.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's template rendering?